# Partial answer and editing own question

Tags: discussion

I've posted a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/608775/how-to-get-the-reference-of-the-result-of-an-array-formula-in-a-list) and got an answer that wasn't totally satisfying but allowed me to solve 90% of my problem. I've accepted the solution of pnuts, but edited my question to the point that it is not really asking anything anymore: the answer is in the text.

So should I delete my question ? Should I mark it with some kind of note ? What the cultural norm around here for that kind of situation ?

Comment: You should restore it to the original revision then simply answer the question yourself providing the entire solution yourself.

Comment: You can always offer a bounty on the question when you get enough reputation, or add a note to the question (NOT including any answers...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, do no edit your question to contain the answers as this can cause confusion and robs others the chance to answer the question as well.  So, [it's ok to answer your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  In fact we encourage it!

Super User (and all other SE sites) encourages learning, including the OP's.  The proper way to handle this is to do as Ramhound has said, revert the question back to it's original form (I've already done that for you) and then take what you did to answer your problem and answer your own question.

Comment: @JoBedard Accept the answer that solved your issue (yes that can be yours).  Upvote the answers that were helpful.